# react-rails gem is not render React component includes Child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-rails

I use React.js and I want to do server side rendering by using ruby gem that is react-rails.

I use it, but a problem is occured.

A Child Component is not rendered.

For example

### Single Component

```
//javascript
class Hoge extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>component</div>
    )
  }
}

//html
<%= react_component('Hoge', {}, {prerender: true}) %>
```

It's OK. It was rendered.

### A Component include child Component.（same file）

```
//javascript
class Fuga extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(<div>Child Component</div>)
  }
}

class Hoge extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(<Fuga />)
  }
}

//html
<%= react_component('Hoge', {}, {prerender: true}) %>
```

It's OK. It was rendered.

### A Component include child Component.（different files）

```
//Fuga.js
class Fuga extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>Child Component</div>
    )
  }
}

// Hoge.js.jsx

import Fuga from './Fuga.js.jsx'
// or var Fuga = require('./Fuga.js.jsx')

class Hoge extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <Fuga />
    )
  }
}

// html
<%= react_component('Hoge', {}, {prerender: true}) %>
```

It's bad. An error occured.

```
// rails error
ActionView::Template::Error (ReferenceError: unknown: console is not defined):
```

Please tell me why that error occured.

Thank you for your patient with my poor English!

Comment: Did you try exporting a child component as a module from another file?

Comment: what was your answer to self question, do u solved it?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by calling 
    ReactRailsUJS.mountComponents()
on the web page. Create a JS file that would call the script above on page load. This causes all components to become available on the web page, thus any references to other components should work. 
Here's an extract  from the react-rails [docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails):

> You can also mount & unmount components from <%= react_component(...)
>   %> tags using UJS:
>
> // Mount all components on the page: ReactRailsUJS.mountComponents()
>   // Mount components within a selector:
>   ReactRailsUJS.mountComponents(".my-class") // Mount components within
>   a specific node: ReactRailsUJS.mountComponents(specificDOMnode)
>
> // Unmounting works the same way: ReactRailsUJS.unmountComponents()
>   ReactRailsUJS.unmountComponents(".my-class")
>   ReactRailsUJS.unmountComponents(specificDOMnode)
>
> You can use this when the DOM is modified by AJAX calls or modal
>   windows.